# How to get the input value of a form / parent component in customer directives in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there any methods by which i can get parent element value in angular custom directives . Can you guys please share me an example

Comment: You can use `@Input` property to [pass data from parent to child](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Comment: @PankajParkar is there any method by which i can get the value directly from parent component inside my custom directives . Because i want to reuse this .

Comment: please add the code sample or stackblitz.

Comment: @cfprabhu  <ngx-editor-menu [editor]-"emailEditor" [toolbar]-"toolbar"> 
</ngx-editor-menu> 

 <ngx-editor [editor]-"emailEditor" appEventChange formControlName="emailTemplate"> </ngx-editor>

Comment: @cfprabhu this is the html i want to get the value of this formcontrol inside my direct. I have multiple editors like this so i want to make this custom directive as a general one so i can reuse it everywhere. Hope you can help me

Comment: If you can pleas make a demo code.